integer promotion in C programming
I have two codes and two question.
Question about first code: Has an integer promotion been made? I mean, y-->Promotion to int -->conversion to Double ? or y--> conversion to Double? which one is true?
Question about second code: Has an integer promotion been made?  I mean, x and y-->Promotion to int?
//First code
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double x=17.123;
    short y=13;
    x+y;
    return 0;
}

//Second Code
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    short x=17;
    short y=13;
    x+y;
    return 0;
}


Read up on this: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8

hi thank's a alot. I will read! can you answer my question please? kind regards.

Promotions are never done when both operands are the same type. So why would the second code need any promotion?

This seems like homework. If it is, you'll learn better by figuring it out yourself.

hi, not homework, I'm tryng to learn c programming and improve my english.

Something you're doing to try to learn is like homework. Post what you think the answer is and why. If you're wrong, we'll explain why and you'll learn.

Note that x+y; as a bare expression in your code does nothing. When testing, are you sure your compiler won't simply optimize this away, making the question about promotion irrelevant?

@Barmar: In one of your previous comments, you wrote: "Promotions are never done when both operands are the same type." -- I believe that this statement is incorrect. In the link to the ISO C11 standard posted by someone else, the standard states: "Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands." In this sentence, "otherwise" means that if neither of the operands is a floating-point type.

I have researching, Here is the my result: The integer promotions are made if there are only integer types in the expression. First code does not contain any integer promotion. I don't have any idea second code. edit: okey, I understand. there is no integer promotion second code.  By the way, all of my reults are correct?

@AndreasWenzel can you check my last comment?

@İlkerDeveci: I believe your reasoning about the first code is correct. However, in the second code, as far as I can tell, both operands are promoted to int.

@Barmar can you check my last comment?

@AndreasWenzel I misread the first bullet after that as saying no promotions are done.

@İlkerDeveci "I have researching, Here is the my result: The integer promotions are made if there are only integer types in the expression."  That's an oversimplification. It is true for operators that use the rule called the usual arithmetic conversions such as the additive + operator. But not true in case of for example logical &&. It depends on the operator.


Question about first code: Has an integer promotion been made? I mean, y-->Promotion to int -->conversion to Double ? or y--> conversion to Double? which one is true?

No, there is no integer promotion. For binary +, C 2018 6.5.6 4 says “If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on them.” The usual arithmetic conversions are specified in 6.3.1.8 1. For adding a double and a short, we only need to consider the first two rules:

First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is long double.
Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is double.

So the short is converted to double. The remaining rules in the list begin with “Otherwise” and hence do not apply.
(The type domain refers to real or complex and does not concern us here.)

Question about second code: Has an integer promotion been made? I mean, x and y-->Promotion to int?

Yes, there is an integer promotion. For adding a short and a short, we consider further rules:

Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is float.
Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:…

Thus, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. This converts them both to int, per 6.3.1.1 2:

If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.

